Download not working from the response on Spring Boot
I can't download from the response. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I tried changing content-type to octet-stream, application/pdf, tried not using "produces". If i write it locally instead of downloading, it generates the pdf perfectly. But if i'm trying to download from the response, it doesnt work.
I also tried in multiple browsers just to be sure and that's definitely not the case.
Network tab on chrome shows that content-type and content-disposition are correct (at least correct like i'm asking it to be)
Is there something wrong with my code?
This is my Controller

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/pdf")
public class PdfController {

    private final PdfService pdfService;

    PdfController(PdfService pdfService) {
        this.pdfService = pdfService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/generate", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> createPdf(@RequestBody PendenciasModel pendenciasModel) throws IOException {
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = pdfService.createPdf(pendenciasModel);


        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE);
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename="+ pendenciasModel.getClient().getCpf() +".pdf");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers)
                .body(new InputStreamResource(bis));
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
        }
    }


}



package com.example.demoDownloadPDF;

import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/pdf")
public class PdfController {
/*
    private final PdfService pdfService;

    PdfController(PdfService pdfService) {
        this.pdfService = pdfService;
    }
  */

    @PostMapping(value = "/generate")
    //public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> createPdf(@RequestBody PendenciasModel pendenciasModel) throws IOException {
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> createPdf(@RequestBody Map<String, String> request)  throws IOException {
        try {
            String fileName = request.get("fileName");
            String filePath = "/home/demo/Downloads/Examples/demoDownloadPDF/pdfs/" + fileName;
            System.out.println("filePath =" + filePath);
            File file = new File(filePath);
            FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource(file);
            byte[] pdfContent;
            pdfContent = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfContent);
            //ByteArrayInputStream bis = pdfService.createPdf(pendenciasModel);



            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            //headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
            //headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + pendenciasModel.getClient().getCpf() + ".pdf");
            headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

            return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(new InputStreamResource(bis));
            //return new ResponseEntity<>(new InputStreamResource(bis), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
            System.err.println("NoSuchFileException>>>" + e.getMessage());
            //e.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException>>>"+e.getMessage());
            //e.printStackTrace();
            //return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}


Test File
put pdf files under /home/demo/Downloads/Examples/demoDownloadPDF/pdfs/
ex: demo1.pdf , demo2.pdf , demo3.pdf
Test
compile
mvn clean package 

run
java -jar target your-spring-boot.jar

test
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"fileName": "demo1.pdf"}' -o demo1.pdf http://localhost:8080/api/pdf/generate


curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"fileName": "demo100.pdf"}' -o demo100.pdf http://localhost:8080/api/pdf/generate

Summary
Because I don't know some of the categories you use, I can only simulate it. The above code can download the pdf file normally. The difference is that I am reading a fixed file. You should be able to easily change it to your writing method. Because I have preserved all your writing methods with comments.
Your code: @RequestBody PendenciasModel pendenciasModel
My Test: @RequestBody Map<String, String> request
Your code:
ByteArrayInputStream bis = pdfService.createPdf(pendenciasModel);
My Test:
byte[] pdfContent;
pdfContent = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfContent);

Your Code:
headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
My Test:
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
Your Code:
headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + pendenciasModel.getClient().getCpf() + ".pdf");
My Test:
headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Your Code:
return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
My Test:
return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
I am test and run my code ok.
